# Twitter4j interfaces and class structure

Tags: java, interface, twitter, twitter4j

The twitter4j packages are not clear to me. For instance how would I retrieve 500 tweets containing a certain hashtag? How would I declare a user and get all their tweets in the past week? For example, I would like the following:

```
User brit = new User("Britney Spears");
List<Tweet> britTweets = brit.getAllTweets();   //assuming this method exists
```

My problem is I cannot instantiate a User since it is declared abstract! What I see so far is a bunch of interfaces with a set of great functions that I do not know how to use.

1. Could someone show me the structure of this library so I can figure out how to use it?
2. What objects can I instantiate to use methods from the trending, User, and timeline interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by looking at the [Code Examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) in the Twitter4J documentation.  Note that for some examples you need to have OAuth credentials configured in twitter4j.properties.

Basically, everything starts with a `Twitter` object.

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
```

By looking at the javadoc, you can see that the [`TwitterImpl`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.html) returned by the factory method implements lots of different interfaces, so there are many, many methods available through the `twitter` reference.  It looks like [`TimelineMethods`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelineMethods.html) are what you want, specifically the [`getUserTimeline`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelineMethods.html#getUserTimeline%28long,%20twitter4j.Paging%29) method that takes a `userId` as a parameter, or the one that takes a user's `screenName`.

Also check out what's available in the [`TrendsMethods`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TrendsMethods.html) and [`SearchMethods`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/SearchMethods.html) interfaces (both also implemented by the `TwitterImpl` class).